# D3.js enter() data() remove() exit()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, save, nodes, children

I've read the bl.ocks documents and tried to my best (many times) to save the data used in my d3 tree.

I'm using this [as my base code](https://medium.com/code-wave/building-a-tree-with-d3-537d43cbd9ab) which is now SQL driven.

I've created code with help of "Coderino" that steps through each node and returns its parent-child relationship (see below)

```
d3.selectAll('g.node')

.each(function(p){
p.children.map(function(c) {        
    alert( c.name +"("+ c.id+")"+ "- PARENT TO -" + p.name + "(" + p.id +")" )

     });    
});
```

**However** when I delete or add a node it doesnt register it in the children.map.

I've tried to insert  node.exit().remove();  link.exit().remove(); into the code for updating the nodes, doesnt seem to effect this either.

Does anyone know if there is a simple function that I could call then run the loop I have to include the new nodes ?

**BUT** if I run this loop

```
d3.selectAll('g.node')

.each(function(p){
    alert( p.name  )

});
```

It sees the new names - so maybe its the p.children.map that needs to be refreshed somehow ? (How would I achieve that !!)

Further testing shows that **IF** you append to the main node (node 1) the functions will read the new node, but appending to any child it wont see them...

Thank you for reading this and any help, comments will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry i do not understand what is the expected behaviour of this.

Comment: Hi Nicola, thank you for responding. Im trying to press a button and return every child and parent in the tree - which works. However, IF you add a new node it will work with nodes added directly to the Main root, but NOT to any children.